# How to select an item by text/label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK. I see the duplicate link above..
I'll try above and see if that works for me.
Thanks.

This should be something very simple, but I cannot find a way to do this.

If I have a "select" control something like this:

```
<select id="gate">
    <option value='Gateway 1'>Gateway A</option>
    <option value='Gateway 2'>Gateway B</option>
</select>
```

I can use the .val() function to programmatically select an item by value like this:

```
$("#gate").val('Gateway 1');
```

**But if I want to use the text or the label to select an item, how do I do that? (i.e. I want to use the string "Gateway B" to select that option).**

I've seen some stuff using "option", but haven't find a way to work.

As you can tell I'm a newbie to the UI stuff.
On the side, one other question I have is that a code like below:

```
$("#gate").val('Gateway 1');
```

Is that standard JavaScript?  JQuery? or HTML?
Where can I find what sort of function I can call on $("#gate") object
and what sort of options there are that I can pass and use?

Comment: You are using Jquery, not quite sure what your question is though

Comment: My question is.. how do I programmatically select an item using the text label, not by the option value.